# Center of mass of the three pennies?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, mathematical-physics

[image]

Three pennies each of radius R and mass M  attached at their edges. How to find the center of mass of the three pennies?

Comment: Symmetry will tell you where it is. In what form should the answer be?

Comment: I want to find the distance of the center of mass from each center of the pennies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the equilateral triangle $ABC$ with corners the centres of the circles. Let $O$ be the centre of mass.

Now there are various ways to proceed. For example, drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$, meeting $AB$ at $X$. Note that $AX=R$.  Then $\frac{R}{OA}=\cos(30^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. It follows that $OA=\frac{2R}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: in the solution they have written that, the center of each penny to the center of mass is just $R/ \cos 30^0$ which is $\frac{2R}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: That is the answer I got. I earlier had a more awkward solution using the Cosine Law.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, the center of mass is the barycenter of the triangle with vertex on the centers of the three pennies.